# How to pass an array from AngularJS up python and store?

Tags: python, arrays, json, angularjs, cherrypy

I need to pass from AngularJS to python a JSON object. JSON structure would be:

```
{ "name": "Bob",
  "address": "Springfield",
  "cars": [
    { "model": "Renault C15", "year": "1965" },
    ...
    { "model": "Ford Ka", "year": "1998" } ]
}
```

This is a fragment of my AngularJS controller. All parameters are input from an HTML form (in this case the array "cars" has been created manually, to show you the way I have it programmed)

```
$scope.cars= [];
var car1 = { model: 'Renault C15', year: '1965' };
var car2 = { model: 'Ford Ka', year: '1998' };
$scope.cars.push(car1);
$scope.cars.push(car2);
...
$scope.newForm = function() {
    var dataToSend= {
        name: $scope.name,
        address: $scope.address,
        cars: $scope.cars
    };
    $http({
        method: 'POST',
        url: '/myUrl/something',
        data: $.param(dataToSend),
        headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'}
    });
    ...
}
```

If I inspect the POST request I see the following parameters:

```
name Bob
address Springfield
cars[0][model]  Renault C15
cars[0][year]   1965
cars[1][model]  Ford Ka
cars[1][year]   1998
```

Initially, I will not know how many items will have the array "cars".
Now, this is the header of a python function. I know how to store the normal arguments but I don't know how to do the same thing with array "cars". I would store it as a python list or dictionary.

```
def something(self, **params):
    ...
    name=params['name']
    address=params['address']
    ...
```

How can I store the array?

Comment: Why are you using `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`?

Comment: It looks like you are trying to send your JSON as parameters, is that right? Why not just send it as data instead? You can then use the json import to turn it into a dictionary or whatever you want at that point.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I won't tell you about AngularJS part as it's out of my interest, but I can tell you about CherryPy. It is be much easier for you to send and process your data as `application/json`, so I suggest you to avoid `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` and search how to send JSON with your client library. With CherryPy, of course, you can handle both ways.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-


import cherrypy


config = {
  'global' : {
    'server.socket_host' : '127.0.0.1',
    'server.socket_port' : 8080,
    'server.thread_pool' : 8
  }
}

class App:

  @cherrypy.expose
  def index(self):
    return '''<!DOCTYPE html>
      <html>
      <head>
        <title>CherryPy demo</title>
        <script type='text/javascript' src='http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js'></script>
        <script type='text/javascript'>
          var data = { 
            "name": "Bob",
            "address": "Springfield",
            "cars": [
              { "model": "Renault C15", "year": "1965" },
              { "model": "Ford Ka", "year": "1998" }
            ]
          };

          $(document).ready(function()
          {
            $('#send-json').on('click', function()
            {
              $.ajax({
                'type'        : 'POST',
                'dataType'    : 'JSON',
                'contentType' : 'application/json',
                'url'         : '/jsonin',
                'data'        : JSON.stringify(data),
                'success'     : function(response)
                {
                  console.log(response);  
                }
              });
            });
            $('#send-form').on('click', function()
            {
              $.ajax({
                'type'        : 'POST',
                'dataType'    : 'JSON',
                'url'         : '/formin',
                'data'        : data,
                'success'     : function(response)
                {
                  console.log(response);  
                }
              });
            });            
          });
        </script>
      </head>
      <body>
        <p><a href='#' id='send-json'>Send JSON</a></p>
        <p><a href='#' id='send-form'>Send form</a></p>
      </body>
      </html>
    '''

  @cherrypy.expose
  @cherrypy.tools.json_out()
  def formin(self, **kwargs):
    # You can just print a variable a see it in the terminal
    # where CherryPy is executed
    print(kwargs)
    # You would see
    # {
    #   'cars[1][year]': u'1998', 
    #   'name': u'Bob', 
    #   'cars[0][model]': u'Renault C15', 
    #   'address': u'Springfield', 
    #   'cars[0][year]': u'1965', 
    #   'cars[1][model]': u'Ford Ka'
    # }
    return kwargs.items()

  @cherrypy.expose
  @cherrypy.tools.json_in()
  @cherrypy.tools.json_out()
  def jsonin(self):
    data = cherrypy.request.json # just the same structure
    return data.items()


if __name__ == '__main__':
  cherrypy.quickstart(App(), '/', config)
```

Comment: It works! I didn't know nothing about json tools included in Cherrypy. Thank you!